# program to simulate keypressing and holding mouse buttons down

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I need a program that can simulate pressing some number keys then holding down mouse buttons for in game testing. Is there a program that can do this?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotkey is tops for keyboard/mouse automation!  AutoHotkey.com

Answer (score 0):

Try the automation language [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/). It's very easy to learn... You can compile the script into an exe-file.